# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el código alfanumérico con procedimientos almacenados consecutivos en jsf?

Tags: java, jdbc, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente procedure en el motor de base de datos MYSQL.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `generacodigo`(
IN prueba VARCHAR(20),
IN idprueba VARCHAR(20),
IN p_codigo VARCHAR(20), 
IN p_ancho INT(20), 
IN valida INT(2), 
OUT result VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN
    DECLARE cadalf VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE valnum TINYINT(2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE  pos TINYINT(2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE bien BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tope INTEGER(20) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cadres VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE poscadact VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @prueba = NULL;

    SET @query = CONCAT("select ",idprueba," into @prueba from ", prueba, " where ",idprueba," = '",p_codigo,"' limit 1");      
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
          EXECUTE stmt1;
          SET result = @prueba;
          DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
          SET result := IFNULL(result,'');
          IF valida = 1 THEN
           SET result := IF(result <> '',-1,result);
          ELSE
            IF LENGTH(p_codigo) = p_ancho THEN
        SET result := IF(result <> '',-1,result);
            ELSE
            SET @query2 = CONCAT("select MAX(",idprueba,") into @prueba from ", prueba, " where ",TRIM(idprueba)," like '",TRIM(p_codigo),"%' limit 1");

            PREPARE stmt2 FROM @query2;
            EXECUTE stmt2;
            SET result = @prueba;            
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
            SET result := IFNULL(result,'');
            IF result = '' THEN
            SET cadalf := '1';
            IF p_codigo <> '' THEN
               SET result := LPAD(cadalf, p_ancho - LENGTH(TRIM(p_codigo)), '0');
               SET result := CONCAT(p_codigo,result);
            ELSE
               SET result := LPAD(cadalf, p_ancho, '0');
            END IF;
            ELSE
               SET pos := 1;

               WHILE pos <= p_ancho DO
              SET poscadact := SUBSTRING(result,pos,1);
              IF poscadact IN('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') THEN
                 SET cadres := CONCAT(cadres, poscadact);
              END IF;

              SET pos := pos + 1;
               END WHILE;
               SET result := CONVERT(cadres,UNSIGNED INTEGER) + 1;
               SET result := LPAD(CONVERT(result,CHAR),p_ancho - LENGTH(TRIM(p_codigo)), '0');
               SET result := CONCAT(p_codigo,result);

            END IF;
            END IF;
          END IF;


END
```

donde:

prueba---> nombre de la tabla a procesar 
idprueba-->campo a generar el código.

Los parámetros para generar.

```
call generacodigo('prueba','idprueba','OC',6,2,@prueba);
SELECT @prueba AS prueba;
```

Ahora mi pregunta es como puedo implementarlo desde java. Dejo parte de mi código pero me genera error No output parameters registered..

public void Numeros() throws Exception{
         ResultSet rs;
         Prueba p=new Prueba();
         try{

```
        this.Conectar();

        CallableStatement st=this.getCn().prepareCall("{generacodigo(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

        st.setString(1,st.getString("prueba"));
        st.setString(2,  st.getString("idprueba"));
        st.setString(3,st.getString("OC"));
        st.setInt(4,st.getInt(6));
        st.setInt(5,st.getInt(2));
        st.setString(6,st.getString("@prueba"));
        st.executeUpdate();

        PreparedStatement st2=this.getCn().prepareCall("SELECT @prueba");
        rs=st2.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            Prueba prueba1=new Prueba();
           prueba1.setIdprueba(rs.getString("@prueba"));
        }   

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }finally{
        this.Cerrar();
    }       
}
```

En el BEAN.

```
public void numeros(Prueba prue)throws Exception{
           PruebaDao dao;
           try{
               dao=new PruebaDao();
               dao.Numeros();   
           }catch(Exception e){
               throw  e;
           }
       }
```

En el `XHTML`.

```
<h:form>
  <p:outputLabel value="codigo alfanumerico" />
  <p:inputText value="#{pruebaBean.prueba}"/>
</h:form>
```

espero si me pueden apoyar muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este problema no está asociado a JSF ni Primefaces en absoluto. Tu problema resulta en cómo consumir el procedimiento almacenado de tu BD. Te recomiendo dos cosas: 1) Indicar el motor de bd que utilizas. 2) Utilizar `CallableStatement` para ejecutar dicho procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: la base de datos esta en Mysql  y la salida del error es el siguiente:Query was empty

Comment: ¿Has probado que tu procedimiento almacenado devuelve los resultados correctos?

Comment: en el motor de base de datos si me arroja los datos correctos  primero llamo procedure llamado generacodigo y despues ejecuto el query select @prueba

Comment: El problema es que desde Java tu conexión no conoce qué significa `@prueba`. En su lugar, deberías aprovechar los beneficios de `PreparedStatement` y `CallableStatement` y colocar los argumentos de tu procedimiento almacenado vía `?` y luego utilizar los métodos `setXyz(<posición>, <valor>)` para registrar los parámetros de entrada y registrar tu parámetro de salida.

Comment: me genera este error: No output parameters registered. y he modificado arriba el codigo

Comment: Es porque el último parámetro debe estar registrado como parámetro de salida.

Comment: por favor me podrías dar un ejemplo con el registro del parámetro de salida @prueba

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado desde tu capa Dao. Para estos casos, JSF y PrimeFaces son irrelevantes durante el análisis. Para utilizar procedimientos almacenados debes utilizar [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). Esta interfaz permite una mejor interacción con estos objetos de base de datos. Puedes crearlo de la siguiente forma:

```
String sql = "{ call generacodigo(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(sql);
cs.setString(1, st.getString("prueba"));
cs.setString(2, st.getString("idprueba"));
cs.setString(3, st.getString("OC"));
cs.setInt(4, st.getInt(6));
cs.setInt(5, st.getInt(3));
//el sexto parámetro es de salida, tienes que registrarlo como tal
//NO DEBES colocarlo como setXyz
cs.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
cs.executeQuery();
//aquí obtienes el valor del sexto parámetro que es de salida
//y lo asignas a tu variable deseada
String prueba = cs.getString(6);
//continúas con el procesamiento de los datos...
```

Puedes encontrar más información en:

- [Java Tutorials. Using Stored Procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) (fuente oficial, en inglés)

Comment: edite y puse una imagen al ultimo no se a que se deberá lo que marca el ide y como solucionarlo

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta. El método se llama `registerOutParameter`. Pero eso significa que solo esperabas que te hicieran el código, ni siquiera te dignas en revisar por tu cuenta qué pudo estar mal y cómo solucionarlo...